# Windows services privilege separation

Tags: windows, permissions, service

When looking at the non-Microsoft services on my computer, most of them are executed as the account SYSTEM. Is there a mechanism in Windows that prevents any service running as SYSTEM from reading/writing data in the folders of other services (seeing as SYSTEM has read/write permissions there)? I read something about each service being its own principal (Service Principal Names), but I'm not sure it's applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

If two services are executed under the same account (whatever its name is) they have the same access to files on the disk.

If you want to separate that, you are going to need to create new accounts. This is very common. For example, when I install FileZilla FTP Server on our Windows servers, I create new user for it. Similarly, when I install Apache web server, I create new user for it. Some software support it on its own, but with most third party software, you need to install it normally, then to stop its service and set it to run under the new user account you have created and start it again.

This will provide you the separation you are looking for. It might seem that there is a lot of work to be done, but if you take your time and create your groups and their users smartly, it is not that bad.

Comment: That's the way I started doing it as well. I just wanted to know whether or not there maybe is a way Windows does this automatically with the SPNs but it seems not.

Comment: No, there is no automatic separation on this level.